# ReSharper inspectcode job failes on CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, resharper, code-inspection

I start to use ReSharper in my project. So, now I try to use ReSharper inspect code job with gitlab ci. There is part of .gitlab-ci.yml file below

```
inspect:
    stage: inspectcode
    script: "jb inspectcode MySln.sln -o=report.xml"
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - report.xml
```

I really want this job to fail if any warnings or errors occur. But it passes. How can I provide that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      codequality: report.xml
```

? Though you might need to find a way (tools should exist) to convert it to a proper json report file (and then use the new report.json file in codequality).

Answer (score 0):

```
   inspect:
    stage: inspectcode
    script: 
      - jb inspectcode MySln.sln -o=report.xml
      - grep -q "<Issues />" report.xml || exit 1
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - report.xml
```

So if there is no Issues, then report.xml will contain

`<Issues />`

Grep will find it and will exit 0 (success).

If there are some Issues, then report.xml will contain
`<Issues> ... </Issues>`

Grep wouldn't find string and || will be executed.

We execute exit 1 (error).

Gitlab-runner checks exit codes to let you know if job is successfull.